# How to pass extra props down to children of arry.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have been trying to pass extra props own to the children being created with the .map function but I have not been able to succeed in passing them succesfully.

This is my code:

```js
export const CommentsListShanghai = (props) => {
  const newTimestamp = props.timestamp;
  console.log(newTimestamp);
  const comments = props.comments;
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
   return (
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => {
      return ( 
        com.adminSpark ? 
          <CommentsModal 
            className="comments-modal"
            data-comments-modal={props.newTimestamp}
            key={ com._id } 
            comment={ com } 
            city={com.city} 
            person={com.person} 
            location={com.location} 
            title={com.title} 
            content={com.content} 
            fileLink={com.fileLink} 
            timestamp={com.timestamp} 
            createdBy={com.createdBy}
            /> :
          <CommentsModal 
            key={ com._id } 
            comment={ com } 
            city={com.city} 
            person={com.person} 
            location={com.location} 
            title={com.title} 
            content={com.content} 
            fileLink={com.fileLink} 
            timestamp={com.timestamp} 
            createdBy={com.createdBy} />
        )
    })}
    </ButtonToolbar> 
   );
  } else {
    return (
      <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
    );
  }
};

CommentsListShanghai.propTypes = {
  comments: React.PropTypes.array,
};
```

I am able to pass all the props of the comments const that I created, the problem is that besides these props I also need to pass an extra prop which is available in the CommentsListShanghai. How am I able to pass an extra props to this array?

I am able to console.log(newTimestamp) without a problem but don't understand how I can pass it down to the .map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
data-comments-modal={props.newTimestamp}
```

just use

```
data-comments-modal={props.timestamp}
```

The `props` here is still referring to the context of `CommentsListShanghai`.

Comment: How can I then add these props to the Modal? 

I have tried newTimestamp={timestamp} but that doesn't work

Comment: Actually I do see them no in my Modal compenent. Refers to as data-comments-modal. But how can I now use these in Modal?

Comment: The props are declared when you set attributes on the component like `className`, `data-comments-modal`, `key`, `comment`, `city`. Those are all now props of `CommentsModal`. Wherever you define `CommentsModal`, you will have access to the props. For example, `CommentsModal = (props) => (<div></div>)`

Comment: It's strange, when I now try to access these props with this.props.data-comments-modal I get an error that comments is not defined.